# Chemistry from a physical perspective

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I'm currently learning chemistry for the first time, and loving it. I have a reasonably good physics and maths background and it's great to see things like spherical harmonics in quantum mechanics "take shape" through chemistry in the form of orbitals. Overall, I am seeing a lot of physics and some mathematics present. However my source is not entirely rigorous, at least by my standards.

Could anyone recommend a text or source that explains chemistry topics from a physics point of view rigorously? Examples of questions I am struggling with (from a physical viewpoint) are Why do bondings occur? What is the distance of seperation? Why is a water molecule bent?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic book is "[Molecular Quantum Mechanics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Molecular-Quantum-Mechanics-Peter-Atkins/dp/0199541426)" by Atkins. Possibly also "The Chemical Bond" by Murrell, Kettle and Tedder, though I think Atkins is better.