# Physics for understanding Chemistry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, soft-question, education, physical-chemistry

I am a highschooler who eventually wants to deeply understand the properties of elements and compounds etc. I have been dabbling in some Chemistry books lately  but I find them  a bit superficial, and thus I have come to realize that I need a good understanding of Physics. What  branches of Physics are the  most related  to these  questions? I think  they are Quantum and Solid  State  Physics  but I am not sure.  And what are the prerequisites  for  these  branches of Physics? Books definitely  do not look beginner-friendly.

I am  aware  that  achieving  a real  understanding  of these  subjects  is  very hard but you have  to start somewhere, right?  I was actually  thinking  to major  in something  related  to Chemistry, but  as I said I have been disillusioned and now I think I will major in something related  to Physics (And I enjoy  Physics as well).

Comment: As for chemistry can be seen a  subfield of physics,  but it is also an applied science in itself,this question should have been posted in chem SE. If you are a cleaver guy/girl and passionate, usually you will find your way along studying. As a comment, with QM professional are still solving H2. On a bench is a different story.  Up to your talent and interest.

Comment: If you take a chemistry major, you will study lots of physics. The most fundamental branches of physics to understand chemistry are without a doubt thermodynamics, statistical mechanics and quantum mechanics, and you will study all of them in every serious chemistry major (even if probably in little less detail than in a physics major).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chemistry from a physical perspective](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78732) or [Where should a physicist go to learn chemistry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6208)

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental subjects in chemistry is the study of bonds between atoms and molecules, which fall into two main categories: intramolecular and extramolecular bonds.

Both these categories contain several forces of different nature, but they all rely on fundamental physical phenomena you might want to study. For example, the understanding of the more recent theories explaining covalent bonds requires a good understanding of quantum mechanics. Understanding electrostatic forces would mean understanding, well, electrostatics...

I would recommend the [Feynman course](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/) to have a good first introduction to fundamental physics concepts. I find it enjoyable to read, although I read it after I learned a bit of physics in university, so I might be a little biased towards it by my previous exposure to the concepts...